# Get Target Path in Gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, gatsby

Is there any way to find the path of the page that a user is on on a Gatsby site and store it in a `const` so that it can be checked next to the current path the user is on? In other words if they're on the `/about` page, and are clicking a link to navigate to the `/contact` page, I need to get the paths of both so that I can check them against each other. I know I can get `location.pathname` for the current url, but how do I find the path that they are navigating to when the click a link?

Comment: Are you using any library for the routes? If not what's the harm in using click event handler on the links?

Comment: I’m not using anything special, no. I just need to be able to check the target path compared to the current path.

Answer (score 0):

Since your code structure isn't clear. Assuming a simple anchor tag, you can do something like this:-

```
<a href="/new/link" onClick={getHref}>New Link</a>
```

And in your `getHref` method

```
 function getHref(event){
  console.log(event.target.href); // should log '/new/link'
}
```

Check if this works in your case.

Please forgive for any typo, I havent validated it.

Answer (score 0):

Gatsby exposes `props` (because it extends from `@reach/router` from React) by default on the top-level components (this means pages). You can pass it to the child components as you wish or store it in a `const` or in a React's state.

Without knowing any page structure, I'll provide something dummy as an example:

```
import React from "react"
import { graphql } from "gatsby"

const YourPage = ({ location, data }) => {
  console.log('your page is ', location.pathname)
  return <div>Dummy content</div>
}

export default Page

export const query = graphql`
  query PageQuery {
    site {
      siteMetadata {
        siteURL
      }
    }
  }
`
```

Your information is stored under `props.location`, that's why you can destructure it in the component's declaration.

In the case above, I've used `pathname` property but you have a bunch exposed. Check it out to find out which one fits your requirements.